# Disposing child UIViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm implementing my own navigation controller. Do I have to manually dispose child UIViewController after I remove it from the navigation controller?

I'm concerned about memory consumption but disposing child controller may lead to unpredictable app crashes depending on where from the Close() method was called. For example, it's a guaranteed app crash if it was called from a child's button event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code, when I receive a memory warning:

AppDelegate:

```
public override void ReceiveMemoryWarning(UIApplication application)
    {
        System.GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: Does it help? I mean did you have a particular problem with memory that was fixed by this code?

Comment: Yes, I received a memory warning in MonoDevelop and my app stopped crashing.